# Displaying more long column names

Tags: r, rstudio

Is there a way to display more characters in a string column of a data table in Rstudio.

For instance:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(StringVar1 = c('This is a very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long string'),
                 StringVar1 = c('This is a short string'))

View(dt)
```

The output will be:

[image]

How can I display the entire content of StringVar1?

Comment: Upgrade to the latest version of `RStudio`. The feature to resize the columns is available in version `1.1.383`.

Comment: Wow, could not come at a better time :) Thanks !